# What's Taylor expansion of: $f(x)=\frac 1x\ln{(1+2x^2)}$?

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

What's Taylor development on the next function: $f(x)=\frac 1x\ln{(1+2x^2)}$?

Actually this one is the first question I've seen with $ln$, My instincts tell me to try and do derivative in order to get a series i can deal with.

But i got to: $-\frac 1{x^2}\ln{(1+2x^2)}+\frac {4}{1+2x^2}$

I know how to deal with: $\frac {4}{1+2x^2}$

But it seems that keep doing derivatives on: $-\frac 1{x^2}\ln{(1+2x^2)}$ won't help that much, How can i develop this function properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** find the Taylor expansion for $\ln(1+z)$, if you don't have it in a table.  From there, substitute $z=2x^2$, and divide (term-by-term) by $x$.

I find this is much easier than directly trying to calculate successive derivatives of $f(x)$.

---

How to deal with the $\frac1x$:

As an example, suppose we were finding the taylor series for $f(x) = \frac1x \sin x$. We know that 
$$\sin x =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$
It follows that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1x \sin{x}&=\frac1x \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac1x \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k+1-1}}{(2k+1)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: How's the multiplication effects the expansion?

Comment: Sorry, made a typo there, should be $z=2x^2$. Does that make more sense?

Comment: It does, But how's the $\frac 1x$ effects the expension?

Comment: I've edited the question to add an explanation.  Is that clear?

Comment: Aye thank you very much.